# React setState not working, getting error

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, setstate

I get the following error when trying to use setState:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null
```

I don't know where I am going wrong, could someone point me in the right direction please.
Here's my code:

```
export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
      return {
        name: '',
        address: '',
        phone: '',
        email: '',
     }
   },

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getUserDetails();
  },

  getUserDetails: function(){
    var personID = 'ABC123'; 
    if(personID.length > 0){
      new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/users/' + personID).on('value', function(snap) {

        this.setState({
          name: snap.val().Name + " " +snap.val().Surname
        });

      });
     }
  },
  render() {
    return ( ... );
  }
});
```

Comment: You need bind `this` to Firebase callback, or use **arrow function** instead. `.on('value', function(snap) { ... }.bind(this)`

Comment: or use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which rely on lexical scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like people have been saying above, if you just edit this to an arrow function it will change the context of `this` from Firebase to the outer scope - which is the component.

```
  new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/users/' + personID).on('value', (snap) => {

    this.setState({
      name: snap.val().Name + " " +snap.val().Surname
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the context of this is not the component anymore. You need this of the component. Check how I grab this of the component.

```
export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
      return {
        name: '',
        address: '',
        phone: '',
        email: '',
     }
   },

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getUserDetails();
  },

  getUserDetails: function(){
    var that  = this
    var personID = 'ABC123'; 
    if(personID.length > 0){
      new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/users/' + personID).on('value', function(snap) {

        that.setState({
          name: snap.val().Name + " " +snap.val().Surname
        });

      });
     }
  },
  render() {
    return ( ... );
  }
});
```